# Gerrit to add notes to Mantis bug

Tags: gerrit, mantis

I would like to have an easy way to add gerrit codes changes with bug reference to the relevant mantis bug.

I have seen some nice example [here](http://bugs.dmdirc.com/view.php?id=4426)

But the use an old php scripts that's not part of mantis anymore and seems to be replaced by the source-intergration plugin that you need to configure for every single project you have. I am looking at adding this for lot's of projects. I rather just copy a hook script in the hook folder for all projects.

Versions:

- Gerrit 2.7
- MantisBT 1.2.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ready solution so I created my own plugin extending the source-integration plugin. Let's see if my boss allows me to contribute this as part of the source-integration plugin.

Comment: I'm interested in your work regarding gerrit and mantis. Do you make it work?

Comment: I am interested too in gerrit/mantis integration. Did you publish your plugin?